# How to write the following constraint?

Tags: constraint, logical-constraints

I would like to write the following constraint, where $varBuyWater$ and $varSellWater$ are decision variables on how much water to buy and to sell. However, I do not want the solver to buy and sell water at the same time, because that makes no sense.

How do I force to solver to have **either** one of them, i.e. if $varBuyWater > 0$ then $varSellWater = 0$ and the other way around. Is there a way to do this>

Comment: If you want to buy and then selling the water, the constraint something like $sellwater \leq buywater$ might be helpful, otherwise, you should use a big-m formulation based on your needs. One example mentioned by @Kuifje.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to introduce a binary variable for buying, $b$, and one for selling, $s$.

Make sure $b$ and $s$ are active when $varBuyWater$ and $varSellWater$ are positive, respectively:
$$
varBuyWater \le M_1 b \\
varSellWater \le M_2 s \\
$$

$M_1$ and $M_2$ are upper bounds on variables  $varBuyWater$ and $varSellWater$.

And impose that both binaries cannot take value $1$ simultaneously:
$$
b+s \le 1
$$